# Css is not editing this class. It works with the <img> tag but not the .tree class?

Tags: html, css

Css is not editing this class. It works with the  tag but not the .tree class?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="firstblock">
       <img class="tree" src="tree.jpg"/>
   </div>
```

Css Code:

```
.tree{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, it should work.

Comment: The image is does not have a width of 10px. It covers my entire <div>. If i use the <img> tag it edits the image just fine in CSS. So i'm confused as to why the class is not working.

Comment: Share complete code snippet so that anyone could understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my HTML and now it works. Maybe Visual Studio Code was bugged. I have no idea.